# Ejecutar archivo .sql desde php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo que realizar un programa en php que ejecute dos archivos .sql, ambos crearán una tabla dentro de mi base de datos 'formadepagos'. Los archivos .sql ya los tengo, sólo tengo que hacer el programa en php.

Este es el archivo sql:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.12, for Win32 (AMD64)
--
-- Host: 158.69.25.165    Database: nexumApp
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS,             FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `formasPago`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `formasPago`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `formasPago` (
`idFormaPago` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`estatus` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idFormaPago`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `formasPago`
--

LOCK TABLES `formasPago` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `formasPago` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `formasPago` VALUES (1,'Nexum Energy Card',1),(2,'GasoPass',1),        (3,'Sodexo',1),(4,'Energex',1),(5,'Visa',1),(6,'Efectivale',1),(7,'UltraGas',1),(8,'Edenred',1),(9,'Visa Electron',1),(10,'Sodexo',1),(11,'Accor',1),(12,'Ticket Car',1),(13,'Mastercard',1),(14,'Credigas',1),(15,'Inbursa',1),(16,'Credigas',1),(17,'American Express',1),(18,'Vale Gasored',1),(19,'PowerGas',1);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `formasPago` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping routines for database 'nexumApp'
--
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2017-02-27 16:28:00
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027769/running-mysql-sql-files-in-php esta puede ser tu mejor opción, pero siempre es mejor usar herramientas tipo PhpMyAdmin, o la consola directa de MySQL, solo como curiosidad, ¿Porqué quieres ejecutarlos desde PHP?

Comment: Acabo de entrar a hacer mi servicio para terminar mi carrera y estoy en capacitación, me pidieron que lo hiciera de esta forma, de hecho ellos me proporcionaron los archivos .sql

Comment: ¿Qué tienes hecho hasta el momento? ¿Podríamos ver un ejemplo de archivo sql?

Comment: Osea, que ni siquiera lo has intentado, has llegado aquí y has preguntado a ver si alguien te lo hace.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yo leería línea a línea el fichero sql e iría insertando las sentencias una vez completadas.

```
// Aquí tendrás que poner tus datos de conexión a la base de datos y la tabla en cuestión.
$conx = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd") or die('Error al conectar');

$fichero = 'formadepagos.sql';  // Ruta al fichero que vas a cargar.

// Linea donde vamos montando la sentencia actual
$temp = '';

// Flag para controlar los comentarios multi-linea
$comentario_multilinea = false;

// Leemos el fichero SQL al completo
$lineas = file($fichero);

// Procesamos el fichero linea a linea
foreach ($lineas as $linea) {

    $linea = trim($linea); // Quitamos espacios/tabuladores por delante y por detrás

    // Si es una linea en blanco o tiene un comentario nos la saltamos
    if ( (substr($linea, 0, 2) == '--') or (substr($linea, 0, 1) == '#') or ($linea == '') )
        continue;

    // Saltamos los comentarios multilinea /* texto */ Se detecta cuando empiezan y cuando acaban mediante estos dos ifs  
    if ( substr($linea, 0, 2) == '/*' ) $comentario_multilinea = true;

    if ( $comentario_multilinea ) {
       if ( (substr($linea, -2, 2) == '*/') or (substr($linea, -3, 3) == '*/;') ) $comentario_multilinea = false;
       continue;
    }

    // Añadimos la linea actual a la sentencia en la que estamos trabajando 
    $temp .= $linea;

    // Si la linea acaba en ; hemos encontrado el final de la sentencia
    if (substr($linea, -1, 1) == ';') {
        // Ejecutamos la consulta
        mysqli_query($conx, $temp) or print('<strong>Error en la consulta</strong> \'' . $temp . '\' - ' . mysqli_error($conx) . "<br /><br />\n");
        // Limpiamos sentencia temporal
        $temp = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: lo intenté de está forma y no me marca ningún error pero tampoco ejecuta el archivo o por lo menos no crea las tablas que debería. Se supone que el archivo sql funciona.

Comment: 1. El fichero se lee correctamente ? Prueba a poner un contador de líneas para ver si se leen todas. 2. La conexión/usuario con la BD es correcta y el usuario tiene los permisos correctos?

Comment: La conexión funciona, el fichero se lee correctamente, pero aún no encuentro manera de ejecutarlo.

Comment: En la línea de mi código donde está el `mysqli_query` añade justo debajo un `echo "$temp<br/>"`, para ver si te está cogiendo correctamente las líneas del fichero SQL. Además añadiría arriba del todo del php una línea con `error_reporting(E_ALL);` para ver todos los posibles errores.

Comment: He modificado un poco la línea donde se comprueba el final del comentario multilínea, porque he visto que los comentarios multilínea del ejemplo acaban en `/*;` y por lo tanto se estaba saltando todo el fichero.

Comment: Me sale Error en la consulta

Comment: He corregido algunos substr que tenían un paréntesis mal. He probado el código en local y no me da error. En tu fichero SQL no hay nada de creación de la database, por lo que a no ser que esté ya creada y la selecciones en el mysqli_connect (el 4 parámetro) obviamente te va a dar error porque no habrá ninguna base de datos seleccionada.

Comment: Ya había seleccionado la base de datos en el mysqli_connect, con las modificaciones que hiciste ya funciona, ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Lo más fácil que veo de hacer, suponiendo que la base de datos este en el mismo servidor donde se ejecuta el php, es lanzar el comando directamente con [system()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.system.php), ya que en una sola línea de código tendrías el problema resuelto.

```
<?php
$comando = 'mysql -u usuario -p contraseña base_a_cargar < archivo.sql';

$ultima_linea = system($comando, $retornoCompleto);

print_r( $ultima_linea );
print_r( $retornoCompleto );
```

Si por el motivo que sea no pudieras utilizar system(), podrías hacerlo con `PHP`, recordemos que `MySQLi` provee funciones para ejecutar [querys múltiples](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php) un ejemplo básico podría ser el siguiente:

```
// Se asume conexión en $mysqli


// Recuperamos el fichero como un string
$fileSQL = file_get_contents('ruta_fichero.sql');


/* Ejecutar consulta multiquery */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($fileSQL)) {
    do {
        /* Almacenar primer juego de resultados */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                print_r($row);
                echo "<br/>";
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* mostrar divisor */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
      // Avanzar al siguiente resultado
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* cerrar conexión */
$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score -2):

Una forma fácil sería con una función similar a esta

```
function ejecutarSQL($_rutaArchivo, $_conexionDB)
{
  $queries = explode(';', file_get_contents($_rutaArchivo));
  foreach($queries as $query)
  {
    if($query != '')
    {
      $_conexionDB->query($query): // Asumo un objeto conexión que ejecuta consultas
    }
  }
}
```

El problema solo lo tendrías en caso de tener comentarios en el fichero sql.

Viendo el problema, la función que puede resolver mejor lo propuesto, será

```
function executeSqlScript($_db, $_fileName) {
    $sql = file_get_contents($_fileName); // Leo el archivo
    // Lo siguiente hace gran parte de la magia, nos devuelve todos los tokens no vacíos del archivo
        $tokens = preg_split("/(--.*\s+|\s+|\/\*.*\*\/)/", $sql, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $length = count($tokens);

    $query = '';
    $inSentence = false;
    $curDelimiter = ";";
    // Comienzo a recorrer el string
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
 $lower = strtolower($tokens[$i]);
 $isStarter = in_array($lower, array( // Chequeo si el token actual es el comienzo de una consulta
     'select', 'update', 'delete', 'insert',
     'delimiter', 'create', 'alter', 'drop', 
     'call', 'set', 'use'
 ));

 if($inSentence) { // Si estoy parseando una sentencia me fijo si lo que viene es un delimitador para terminar la consulta
     if($tokens[$i] == $curDelimiter || substr(trim($tokens[$i]), -1*(strlen($curDelimiter))) == $curDelimiter) { 
  // Si terminamos el parseo ejecuto la consulta
  $query .= str_replace($curDelimiter, '', $tokens[$i]); // Elimino el delimitador
  $_db->query($query);
  $query = ""; // Preparo la consulta para continuar con la siguiente sentencia
  $tokens[$i] = '';
  $inSentence = false;
     }
 }
 else if($isStarter) { // Si hay que comenzar una consulta, verifico qué tipo de consulta es
     // Si es delimitador, cambio el delimitador usado. No marco comienzo de secuencia porque el delimitador se encarga de eso en la próxima iteración
     if($lower == 'delimiter' && isset($tokens[$i+1]))  
  $curDelimiter = $tokens[$i+1]; 
     else
  $inSentence = true; // Si no, comienzo una consulta 
     $query = "";
 }
 $query .= "{$tokens[$i]} "; // Voy acumulando los tokens en el string que contiene la consulta
    }
}
```

Aunque seguramente no será la mas optima que se puede hacer

Comment: Si hay alguna cadena interna con `;` también falla. En plan `INSERT INTO tabla set cadena='texto;texto;texto';`

Answer (score -3):

Desde PHP puedes ejecutar sequencias SQL por ejemplo:

```
   <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("ejemplo.com", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falló la conexión con MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test") ||
    !$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE test(id INT)") ||
    !$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (1)")) {
    echo "Falló la creación de la tabla: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
?>
```

Comment: Creo que esta preguntando como ejecutar archivos fisicos sql no sentencias sql directas.